# Vim syntax off for markdown in .vimrc

Tags: vim

At the moment I use `:syntax off` for markdown. But I'd like to make it syntax off when I edit a markdown file.

I tried this in .vimrc but md files has syntax.

```
"""""syntax off for markdown"""
if &ft=='md'
    syntax off
else
    syntax on
endif
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish it with an auto-command for all buffers for which the filetype is set to "markdown", or "md", like so:

```
autocmd Filetype markdown setlocal syntax=OFF
```

You can read about the syntax of commands Vim can execute automatically with `:help :autocmd`.

Comment: Do I need to add syntax on above this code in .vimrc so that other files get syntax on?

Comment: No, you only need to set file type detection on with `filetype on`.

Comment: But this turn off all other files as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `:set ft?` and `:set syn?` for a Markdown file, and a file of any other type?

Comment: In php file, there is no syntax and outputs are filetype=php and syntax= .(no output) and In a markdown file, outputs are filetype=markdown and syntax= .(no output)

Comment: My bad, forgot `syntax off` works for all buffers. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25829710/vim-how-to-disable-syntax-altogether-for-certain-filetype).

Create ~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim with:

```
setlocal syntax=
```